# Delphi 2010 Soap Client custom address

Tags: delphi, soap, constants

I have make to a client - server Soap application with Delphi 2010.

Server application I make XE stand alone and I planned to running my home computers.

Client - Server integration working without any problems with LocalHost:Port same as below :

const

defWSDL = 'http://Localhost:54000/wsdl/IMySoapServer';

defURL  = 'http://Localhost:54000/wsdl/IMySoapServer';

But I want to assign **my own dinamic server address from my web server**. For example:

const

defWSDL = 'http://**123.123.123.1**:54000/wsdl/IMySoapServer';

defURL  = 'http://**123.123.123.1**:54000/wsdl/IMySoapServer';

When client running, will be get first my actual server address from my web server. Then will be assing to defWSDL and defURL consts. I want to make this.

But I get always "[DCC Error] IMySoapServer.pas(61): E2026 **Constant expression expected**" error.

I tried {$J+} {$J-} and {$WRITEABLECONST ON}. But nothing changed. Consts still unwritable and give to me  same error.

Any way possible to change server addresses? Same like dyndns, just I will use my own server for update server address.

Best Regards,

Comment: No need to change the constants. Just provide your own routine that creates the HTTPRIO client with the URL of your desire...

Comment: Thanks. I moved both string into VAR. I create new defWDSL and defURL after Begin and problems are solved. I did want to use both string under Const. But impossible to change and give always same error. 

Best Regards,